# How to architect Service Broker with three or more systems?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm trying to implement a Service Broker architecture for a business process involving three systems and I want to do it in the spirit of using SB as designed.

- System 'A' is an accounting system. Whenever an invoice is 'released' in
  that system, a SB conversation starts.
- System 'O' is a internally-developed orchestration system. Think of
  it as morally equivalent to BizTalk.
- System 'C' is a database that has information that needs to be
  included on the final invoice to be sent to the customer.

How do I structure a conversation or series of conversations to touch all three systems?

Can I have 'A' submit to 'O', which does a lookup into 'C' - all in the context of a single conversation?

Comment: More specifically, can an activation stored procedure be the initiator of of secondary conversations in a conversation group? That sounds a bit like recursive triggers.

Comment: This article may help you. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Service+Broker/2797/